# Rxjs share operator is not giving the expected results

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I am attempting to get the rxjs operator share working like in https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html, but I am not getting the expected results. I was expecting the 'Running map function' to only log once. Am I missing something?

```js
const { of } = rxjs;
const { map, share } = rxjs.operators;

const obs$ = of('data');

const mapped$ = obs$.pipe(map(d => {
  console.log('Running map function');
  return `mapped ${d}`;
}));

const shared$ = mapped$.pipe(share());

shared$.subscribe(d => { console.log(d); });

shared$.subscribe(d => { console.log(d); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.3.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The problem is that your observable completes. Try preventing that by adding `concat(NEVER)`

Comment: Your source observable is synchronous. `share` reference counts subscriptions, subscribing to the source when the reference count is incremented from 0 to 1 and unsubscribing when the reference count drops to 0. Because the source is synchronous each subscription to your shared source sees the reference count incremented and decremented, so each involves a separate subscription to the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, your subs are sync. To get the expected behavior you can use schedulers. To start with scedulers you can read [this article](https://staltz.com/primer-on-rxjs-schedulers.html), for example

```js
const { of, Observable, asyncScheduler } = rxjs;
const { map, share, observeOn } = rxjs.operators;

const obs$ = of('data').pipe(observeOn(asyncScheduler));

const mapped$ = obs$.pipe(map(d => {
  console.log('Running map function');
  return `mapped ${d}`;
}));

const shared$ = mapped$.pipe(share());

shared$.subscribe(d => { console.log(d); });

shared$.subscribe(d => { console.log(d); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.3.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```